# Why can't I get jGrowl or Sliding Message library working?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I'm trying to get a delayed message to slide in from the right side of the screen after a delay, so I tried two different libraries without success. Neither library does anything.

**[jQuery Sliding Messages](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/jquery-sliding-message) Method**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/jquery-sliding-message/jquery.slidingmessage.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.flyoutMessage = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var options = {id: 'message_from_top',
                     position: 'right',
                     size: 300,
                     backgroundColor: 'red',
                     delay: 1500,
                     speed: 500,
                     fontSize: '30px'
                    };
      $.showMessage("Hello world!", options);
    },
  };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**jGrowl Method**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/jGrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.showAnnouncement = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $.jGrowl("Hello world!", { sticky: true });    
    },
  };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I checked the source, and there is no "Hello world!" message anywhere to be found, and no errors in the console either. I have tried this on two different websites to be sure.

Comment: Could it be that the problem be that you use inline JS, and as such its executed to late/early or so?

Comment: Hmm I will check that out.